# How to stop voice Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis when item deselected

Tags: c#, uwp, accessibility

I am currently trying to add functionality to allow for screen reader use in my app and have been using Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis and .GotFocus to read out button and labels when they are selected by the screen reading device.

My issue however is that the speech doesn't stop when another item is selected so I have everything being read at once.

I have tried using .LostFocus and .Stop() method to try and get around this but sadly to no avail.

Has anyone had luck implementing SpeechSynthesis in an app and item selection?

Comment: Just curious -- does the built-in Narrator not work for your app?

Comment: The app works a treat with the narrator after some automationProperties tweaks, but I was set the task of exploring accessibility without using it.

Answer (score 0):

This is some relevant code I use in one of my apps,

I use a single instance of `MediaElement` to read text.

```
static MediaElement ttsMediaElement;
```

This is the method that converts text to stream and reads it. At the beginning of the method, I stop the `MediaElement`.

```
public static async Task ConvertTextToSpeechAndPlay(string text)
{
    if (ttsMediaElement != null)
            ttsMediaElement.Stop(); //stop the reading that has not finished, if any

    var voice = ChooseVoice(text); //select the preferred voice chosen by the user
    if (voice != null)
    {
        using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            synth.Voice = voice;

            SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);

            ttsMediaElement = new MediaElement();

            ttsMediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
            ttsMediaElement.Play();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Cheers kennyzx, I will give your stop method a bash!